# Returning XML from a Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, web-services

I have an XML file that sits on the hard drive of a Server running my Web Service. I need to access that file from another application.

This is my method on my Web Service

```
Public Function getXMLFile()
    Dim xmlDocument As System.Xml.XmlDocument

    xmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
    xmlDocument.Load("C:\Sommaire.xml")

    Return xmlDocument
End Function
```

When I navigate to my Web Service and try to invoke my method, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the
>   XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument may not be used in this context.

This is caused when I try to return the `xmlDocument` object

From the information I gathered, it's like SOAP wants to wrap my XML in more XML and stops me from doing that.

How do I go about getting the XML File from my Web Service if I can't return XML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function doesn't specify a return type, yet you're trying to return an object of type System.Xml.XmlDocument.

Change

```
Public Function getXMLFile()
```

to

```
Public Function getXMLFile() AS System.Xml.XmlDocument
```

Entire snippet as it should be:

```
Public Function getXMLFile()  AS System.Xml.XmlDocument
    Dim xmlDocument As System.Xml.XmlDocument

    xmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
    xmlDocument.Load("C:\Sommaire.xml")

    Return xmlDocument
End Function
```

Comment: @PeekaySwitch: you should turn `OPTION STRICT ON`, and you won't have this sort of problem.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Oooh, thanks! I will keep that in mind for the future!